# Any good freeware advanced ASP.NET grid control available on the web?

Tags: asp.net

Was just wondering if there were any good free advanced asp.net grid controls that are available for use on the web? I know a few but they are payable and only have free trial versions e.g Telerik Radgrid controls or obout suite.

Comment: What features are you looking for?  What are you looking for beyond the Microsoft provided datagrid?

Comment: I need a grid that is more flexible in the styles i can apply to it. Something that would contain the functions of an ASP.NET gridview but also allows you to style your grid in a better way than the Microsoft control.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

just write your own
hopefully you're not using VB

Comment: nope, using C#. I guess it kind of makes sense to write your own as you never know what may fall upon you using third party controls (one of my mates hates using third party controls).

Comment: Not sure why C# or VB matters in this case. Both languages are increasingly on par in .NET. @unknown - Any reason for the VB over C# advice in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you use [CSS Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/GridView.aspx) you will be able to style your grids a little better

Answer (score 0):

You could try "webgrid"...[link](http://webgrid.com) I have not yet used it but it does look pretty impressive

Answer (score 0):

*[Full disclosure: Yes, I work for Telerik.]*

Styling for web controls- or "skins"- is one of the common reasons people use 3rd party controls for ASP.NET. I'm actually always surprised by how many people vote this as one of their top reasons for using Telerik's tools. In case you do consider using 3rd party tools, I wanted to highlight a recently introduced (free) tool from Telerik that makes it even easier to build custom skins for Ajax controls:

[Telerik Visual Style Builder](http://stylebuilder.telerik.com)

Between our built-in skins and this customization tool, you can save -a lot- of time creating good looking Grids that work in all modern browsers (that last part can be the biggest time drain if you try to build the HTML and CSS on your own).

As an Microsoft MVP and avid web developer, I also wanted to comment on the idea of "rolling your own is always better."

While a homegrown solution may perfectly fit your project today, there are a number of important drawbacks to this approach you should consider:

- Unless you are going to "innovate" in the area of web grids and in-turn your work on a custom grid contributes to your business' bottom line, you're just re-inventing the wheel. And by the time you're done, you'll have spent much more in your personal time building and testing your grid than you would have paying for a quality component.
- Will you be the only person to ever support this application? If this application at some point in the future may need to be supported by other people, "homegrown" solutions are particularly painful. There is usually no documentation and no guarantee that the M&P Team can find you to provide support. You actually improve the long-term maintainability of your app by using documented, supported 3rd party tools.

I did a blog post along the lines of this topic a few years ago that you may want to check-out:

[The Definitive UI Component Metaphor](http://weblogs.asp.net/toddanglin/archive/2008/02/19/the-definitive-ui-component-metaphor.aspx)

Of course, I always understand the desire as a software developer to tackle a challenge and be a craftsman, so sometimes we all need to build our own control to scratch that itch. Hopefully these ideas give some additional perspective, though.